# Updating a config file through docker-compose

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I am trying to get xdebug to work in a php container within a docker-compose setup. I found a few examples that show the extra config lines that need to be added to the container:

From Reddit, I have tried to add these lines in my web container's Dockerfile:

```
    # Configure xdebug
    RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
    RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
    RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
    RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=10.10.1.2" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

But I am not directly using a dockerfile as far as I can tell.

```
    my docker-compose.yml:

    web:
      image: tutorial/nginx
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      volumes:
        - ./src:/var/www
        - ./src/vhost.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/vhost.conf
      links:
        - php

    php:
      image: nmcteam/php56
      volumes:
        - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
        - ./src:/var/www
      run:
        # Configure xdebug
        RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
        RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
        RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
        RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=10.10.1.2" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
      links:
        - db

    db:
      image: sameersbn/mysql
      volumes:
       - /var/lib/mysql
      environment:
       - DB_NAME=demoDb
       - DB_USER=demoUser
       - DB_PASS=demoPass
```

Clearly the run: section does not work. I'm missing something, but so far have not been able to get my head around how to solve the problem using compose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`run` is not a command in [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/)

you can specify either `image` or `build` with alternative path to a `Dockerfile`

So you can use `RUN` in your `Dockerfile`. [Reference](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/reference/builder/)

My recommendation is that if you need to run the commands you specified, you can do something like this for your 'php' `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nmcteam/php56
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_host=10.10.1.2" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini
```

Build the image:

```
docker build -t myuser/php56 <path to Dockerfle>
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` file, in the 'php' section:

```
php:
  image: myuser/php56
  volumes:
    - ./src/php-fpm.conf:/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf
    - ./src:/var/www
  links:
    - db
```

You can optionally push your image to your dockerhub account:

```
docker push myuser/php56
```

Comment: Thank you for this - I have my php container now debuggable from phpstorm.

RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini 
should read
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=0" >> /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini